# Bootstrap collapse odd behavior with no href and onClick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, collapsable

I'm trying to understand *why* this Bootstrap Collapse issue is occurring.

Using a simple collapse set up like so:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example">Tap To Show</a>
<div id="example" class="collapse ">
  <p>Example Shown</p>
</div>
```

On desktop it works fine but on mobile the collapse does not show on tap.

However, if you put an empty onClick attribute on the  it works fine on mobile, like this:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example" onClick="" >Tap To Show</a>
<div id="example" class="collapse ">
  <p>Example Shown</p>
</div>
```

Why does the onClick allow the collapse to work?

Example Here: https://jsfiddle.net/ghe8jt03/ 
*(1st toggle wont work, 2nd toggle will)*

Comment: On iOS 11.3 using Safari neither option works.

Comment: @RobertC odd I'm on 11.3 Safari as well (also tried Chrome) and only the second works.

Comment: this is a example: https://jsfiddle.net/uhc08wpb/